# Checking if a DIV is currently shown on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, fadein

I'm learning jQuery and this is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login').click(function(){
        $('#login-box').fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
</script>
```

It works, when you click the login button the DIV called `login-box` shows on the page. What I wanted to do was if the login button was clicked again, the `login-box` DIV will fade from the page. What would be the best way to do this? I was thinking:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login').click(function(){
        if(login-box-is-showing)
        {
            $('#login-box').fadeOut('fast');
        } else {
            $('#login-box').fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

But I'm confused at how I would determine if the DIV is showing or not. I also see that jQuery has a toggle function, would that be better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [Karl Swedberg](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/bd9ab1487def3fc8/a24286723ec3ab98?pli=1)

```
jQuery.fn.fadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) { 
   return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback); 
};
```

Then, you can do this:

```
$("#login").click(function () { 
         $("#login-box").fadeToggle() 
 });
```

Comment: Matt, you should change your question. The selected answer doesn't address the question you posed.

Comment: +1, but you should have also given an example using speed, easing, and the optional callback (or set defaults within the function);

Answer (score 4):

`$("#login-box:visible")` will tell you if it's visible, while `$("#login-box:hidden")` tells you if it's not. However, an easier way of handling this would be to use [`$.toggle()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle) or even [`$.slideToggle()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideToggle#speedcallback) if you want a bit of an added effect.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use [toggle()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle#speedcallback).

Comment: Thanks. toggle probably is better. Although how can I make the effect fade? I don't see any parameters that toggle accepts to chose what effect you want?

Comment: ~Joel, fadeToggle() doesn't seem to be a jQuery function?